# Problem in C# .net web application Redirection

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, httpmodule, response.redirect

I coded this httpmodule and added it correctly to the site but it give me this error when I run it:

**The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the
request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

```
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;

    namespace CommonRewriter
    {
        public class ParseUrl : IHttpModule
        {
            public ParseUrl()
            {

            }

            public String ModuleName
            {
                get { return "CommonRewriter"; }
            }

            public void Init(HttpApplication application)
            {
                application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(application_BeginRequest);
                application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(application_EndRequest);
            }


            private string ParseAndReapply(string textToParse)
            {
                string final = null;

                if (textToParse.Contains(".") && textToParse.Contains("example.com"))
                {
                    string[] splitter = textToParse.Split('.');
                    if (splitter[0].ToLower() != "www" &&(splitter[2].ToLower()).Contains("blog"))
                    {
                        final = ("www.example.com/Blog/?tag=/" + splitter[0]);
                    }
                    else { final = textToParse; }
                }
                else { final = textToParse; }

                return final;
            }

            void application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
                HttpContext context = application.Context;

                string req = context.Request.FilePath;
                context.Response.Redirect(ParseAndReapply(req));
                context.Response.End();
            }


            void application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            public void Dispose() { }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Every begin request is redirecting, even to the same url. You need a check to make sure that redirection is necessary before calling `context.Response.Redirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in:

```
 context.Response.Redirect(ParseAndReapply(req));
```

BeginRequest event signals the creation of any given new request. So in every redirect, it's getting called. And in your code, it's redirected to a new request which causes an infinite loop. Try to reconsider your logic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the recusion problem listed in other answers, it looks like you are redirecting to a relative path (www.example.com/Blog/?tag=/....)

Try http://www.example.com/Blog/?tag=/....

Answer (score 0):

In `application_BeginRequest` you are redirecting ***every*** request via `context.Response.Redirect(ParseAndReapply(req));`

You should check if a condition is true before redirecting, such as

```
string req = context.Request.FilePath;
if (req.Contains(".") && req.Contains("example.com"))
{
    context.Response.Redirect(ParseAndReapply(req))
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the argument for ParseAndReply doesn't contain "example.com", it will infinitely redirect onto itself.

One other note:

```
if (textToParse.Contains(".") && textToParse.Contains("example.com"))
```

is redundant.  "example.com" will always contain '.'

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. originally it was just `textToParse.Contains(".")` I added the "example.com" part later

Comment: The site im working on is a dev site with an ip address instead of a domain name. im using the host file to change the ip into a usable domain. is it poisible that the `string req = context.Request.FilePath;` is returning an ip address for evaluation instead of a text domain name.

Comment: The hostname shouldn't matter.  Filepath returns the file and path portion of the URL, and doesn't include the hostname or any query string values.  The only way your redirect condition will fire is if you have a URL like "h ttp://somesite.com/example.com/file.aspx?arg=val1&arg2=val2"
FilePath will return "/example.com/file.aspx" from that example.

Comment: well that helps me a lot. would using the `context.Request.RawUrl` return the whole url

Comment: That still only provides path and query information.  You probably want to work against the Request.Url object.  If you need the full string, you can call Request.Url.ToString() to get it.  But it looks like you're parsing it anyway, and System.Uri (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) already does a lot of the heavy lifting for that parsing already.

Comment: i got it figured out i needed to use ` string req = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;` instead of `context.Request.RawUrl`